# How can I convert ListView population from JSON to SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, json, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a listview in a fragment that is populated with a list of events. I have a heart icon on these list items that allows the user to click and favorite the items. I am currently saving the event id in sharedprefs when the item is Favorited.

[image]

This is working properly, and saves the favorited item across user sessions. I now need to populate these favorited items in the favorites listview. The old developer tried a JSON implementation from an api, but it never worked. I now just want to populate this list from the sharedprefs. Heres my favorites fragment code...

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import lakeviewlabs.ticketliquidator.api.delete_favorites.DeleteFavoritesApi;
import lakeviewlabs.ticketliquidator.api.delete_favorites.DeleteFavoritesApiOut;
import lakeviewlabs.ticketliquidator.api.get_favorites.GetFavoritesApi;
import lakeviewlabs.ticketliquidator.api.get_favorites.GetFavoritesApiOut;

import static com.urbanairship.UAirship.getApplicationContext;

public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment implements GetFavoritesApiOut, DeleteFavoritesApiOut {

    View rootView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    FavoritesAdapter adapter;
    Boolean checkState = false;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Map<String, Object> eventValue = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().trackEvent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "View Favorites",eventValue);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " +
                    entry.getValue());

            if (entry.getKey().matches("[0-9]+") && entry.getValue().equals(true)) {
                Log.d("using values",entry.getKey() + ": " +
                        entry.getValue());
                //     performersList.add(entry.getKey().);
            }
        }

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);

        GetFavoritesApi api = new GetFavoritesApi(getContext(), this);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete_favorites).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteFavorites();
            }
        });

        showLoadingMessage();

        api.get();
        return rootView;

    }

    private void deleteFavorites() {
        ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favorites);
        DeleteFavoritesApi api = new DeleteFavoritesApi(getContext(), this);

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++){
            View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_select);
            if(check.isChecked()){
                ids.add(view.getTag().toString());
            }
        }

        if(ids.isEmpty()){
            onDeleteFavoritesSuccess();
            return;
        }

        api.delete(android.text.TextUtils.join(",", ids));

    }

    private void showLoadingMessage(){
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting favorite performers...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onGetFavoritesSuccess(JSONArray favorites) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favorites);

        ArrayList<JSONObject> performersList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        for(int i = 0; i < favorites.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject performer = null;

            try {
                performer = favorites.getJSONObject(i);
                performersList.add(performer);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getContext(), performersList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(checkState) {
                    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_select);
                    check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), PerformerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("performer_id", view.getTag().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onGetFavoritesError(JSONObject errors) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGetFavoritesUnexpectedError() {

    }

    public void showCheckboxes() {

        checkState = !checkState;

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete_favorites).setVisibility(checkState ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favorites);

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++){
            View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_select);
            check.setVisibility(checkState ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            check.setChecked(false);
//            view.animate()
//                .translationX(150)
//                .setDuration(300)
//                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
//
//                    }
//                });
        }

//
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteFavoritesSuccess() {
        GetFavoritesApi api = new GetFavoritesApi(getContext(), this);
        showLoadingMessage();
        showCheckboxes();
        api.get();
    }
}
```

I've tried parsing all the sharedprefs and Im able to log the ones that are needed. I just cant get them to display in the favorites list.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object of the item as JSON string in the Shared Preferences and whenever new item is added to favorites append the JSON object for that item to the JSON string and in the Favorites list read and parse the json string from Shared Preferences. I'm assuming you get the results in JSON array from the API. I would suggest store the JSON string  in the same format as received so that you can reuse the same POJOs for favorites list. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This will probably be what I have to do. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store your preferences like that. Storing your event using their ids as a key creates a big mess in your Shared Preferences. 
Instead:

- Store a list of event id. As you can't store a list in the Shared Preferences, use Gson to convert your list into a Json string. Then store the string. Use Gson again to regenerate the list from the stored string.
- The other (better) option, is to use a local database. It's gonna be easier, and cleaner. You will be able to store more information easily. Like that you can store the entire event (and not the id only) and request them back to populate your ListView of favourite events

Note: You could store the entire events in the Shared Preferences as suggested by @Varun_Ramani but it's not recommended as the purpose of the Shared Preferences is not to replace databases (as explained in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), see below).

> If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs.

Comment: In theory it will be a small number of sets saved. Shouldnt be more than 10 or so really.

Comment: Idk how is your event object (big/small), and what you try to achieve exactly. You can store them in the Shared Preferences as it's gonna be quicker to implement but maybe you'll realise at some point that's better with a database. In anycase store them (the entire list) as a Json string under one unique key like "key_favourite". You need to know what keys you've used to store the data otherwise it's impossible (very difficult) to retrieve them.